# Enable Disable XP WIFi using command line

Tags: batch-file, registry, windows-xp

Help me out to, Enable and Disable WIFI in my XP using Command Line.

Tried with:
   netsh interface set interface name="Wireless Network Connection " admin=disabled
but it is showing, More data to display.

Also, "netsh interface show interface"
Does not display any Interface name.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's command should work fine. Are you sure it's not disabled? is there really connection available with name `Wireless Network Connection`?

In your command, try replacing `Wireless Network Connection` with actual connection name like `Local Area Connection`

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

Also if below command is not displaying then I doubt, you have any network interface configured. Check to make sure that.

```
netsh interface show interface
```

You can as well use the below alternative way to enable/disable a specific connection [Quoted from [MS Community Answer](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/enabledisable-network-interface-via-command-line/17a21634-c5dd-4038-bc0a-d739209f5081)]

> Start elevated Command Prompt.
>
> Get NIC list and index number:
>
> ```
> wmic nic get name, index
> ```
>
> Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
>
> ```
> wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
> ```
>
> Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)
>
> ```
> wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
> ```